# Integrating Skype with Internet DJ Console

Tags: skype

I am an internet radio host, and I have been trying to integrate Skype with the Internet DJ Console.

Everything I've found on the web regarding this is at least two years old, and not of much use. It shows screencaps of JACK with ALSA DEDICATED PORTS, which even with the alsa plugin does not appear in the Connection Window of JACK Control, nor can I find an `idjcskype` plugin that will actually work.

Comment: Could you provide the links of what have you tried and the results?

Comment: Hey, Mike. I've tried shell scripts, and nothing, Ijust found inteh change log, that scripts are no longer necessary, but no routing info. I have installed JACK SINK and it is working, now, I need to figure out routing. I found a few youtube videos, but they are of no help in that, as they don't show nor explain the routing set up. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZu71ncLDk4 (it's in Spanish)